# Submit only changed fields in angular

Tags: angularjs

Suppose that I have a form as follow and i need to issue a patch request which only need to patch value that is being modified to the server.

I have discover two ways to do it: 
1) Manually loop through the $scope.form and check if it is pristine state and return non-pristine value 
2) Save a copy of the original value, compare it with the final value before submission using loop and return only those value that is different from the original copy and submit

But i think that both of the ways need to manual edit and data manipulation out of the box. Is there any existing built in way in angular like `$scope.myForm.getNonPristine()` as i think this is quite a common issue out there? If no, which are a more better approach?

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="first" ng-model="form.firstName">
    <input type="text" name="last" ng-model="form.lastName">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there is no built in ways. Just use the 1-st approach. Select only $dirty fields.